# Why in Spring application I get null as user when using @AuthenticationPrincipal?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring connecting to KeyCloak to provide authentication in my application, but ran into a problem. Here is a part of my code:

```
@GetMapping("/api/user/name")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUserName(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Authentication: " + authentication);

    if (user != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User not authenticated");
    }
}
```

When calling this method, I have the user variable always set to null. I expect to get information about the authenticated user. Here is the configuration of my Spring application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestOauth2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestOauth2Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll());

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/manager.html").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/test/test").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        converter.setPrincipalClaimName("sub");
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
            var authorities = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt);
            var roles = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("spring_sec_roles");

            return Stream.concat(authorities.stream(),
                            roles.stream()
                                    .filter(role -> role.startsWith("ROLE_"))
                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                    .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                    .toList();
        });

        return converter;
    }


    @Bean
    public OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oAuth2UserService() {
        var oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();
        return userRequest -> {
            var oidcUser = oidcUserService.loadUser(userRequest);
            var roles = oidcUser.getClaimAsStringList("spring_sec_roles");
            var authorities = Stream.concat(oidcUser.getAuthorities().stream(),
                            roles.stream()
                                    .filter(role -> role.startsWith("ROLE_"))
                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                    .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                    .toList();

            var nameAttribute = userRequest.getClientRegistration()
                    .getProviderDetails()
                    .getUserInfoEndpoint()
                    .getUserNameAttributeName();
            var name = oidcUser.getAttribute(nameAttribute);
            oidcUser.getAttributes().put("name", name);

            return new DefaultOidcUser(authorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());
        };
    }
}
```

And I'm sending the next token:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6eTdPbVN1b3NTVGJCUlhEYnRzZFBtOUtDV3FBQWZhQy1iMzh6RHBVOTlVIn0.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
```

UPD.
But at the same time, `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` works for me.

Maybe I don't fully understand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual type you get with `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` will change depending on how you authorize your request (a browser session with login or a Bearer token in a request from a REST client).

`OidcUser` is the principal of `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` for an authenticated user on an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` in an OIDC environment (which is the case with Keycloak).

Requests to OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login` are authorized using session cookie, not with `Bearer` access token in `Authorization` header.

`Bearer` access token in `Authorization` header authorize requests to a resource  servers. Default authentication in resource server is `JwtAuthenticationToken`, which has a principal of type `Jwt`.

Mixing configuration with `oauth2Login` and `oauth2ResourceServer` in the same security filter-chain is a very bad idea, the security requirements are too different:

- `oauth2Login`: security based on sessions, requires protection against CSRF and it is generally expected that unauthorized requests to protected resources are redirected to login (`302` status code)
- `oauth2ResourceServer`: security based on access token, can (should?) be stateless (no session), insensible to CSRF and it is expected that unauthorized requests to protected resources are answered `401` (login makes no sense on resource server)

I don't see a valid use case for having both flavors of security on a single endpoint.